# Tips for golfing in Z80 or SM83 machine code

Tags: code-golf, tips, assembly, machine-code

There's only one question for machine-language golfing, and it's for the ia32 and amd64 architectures. Here's one for a predecessor of them: the Zilog Z80!

The ISA is available [here](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/opcode-reference-chart).

As usual, if your tip is only applicable to a certain environment/calling convention, please indicate that in your answer.

> Only one tip per answer (see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9296)).

You can also offer tips for the closely related Sharp SM83.
The ISA for that is available [here](https://www.pastraiser.com/cpu/gameboy/gameboy_opcodes.html).<sup>1</sup>

Please mark your tips as to whether they're applicable to Z80, SM83, or both; the ISAs might be similar, but there are many differences.

1. It's labeled as the LR35902; that's the SiC that was used in the DMG and CGB. It had an SM83 core.

Answer (score 3):

### Shadow registers

When you're short on registers, you can use the shadow registers - `af'`, `bc'`, `de'` and `hl'`. These registers map directly to their usual counterparts (without `'`). You can exchange registers using `ex reg, reg'` or `exx`. The later exchanges all registers (`af` and `af'`, `bc` and `bc'`, etc...). Drawbacks:

- not compatible with "usual" registers, you can't use for example `ld` to assign from a standard to a shadow register.
- they were originally meant to be used inside ISRs, so the interrupts should be disabled while you use them.

Comment: Note that `ex reg,reg'` has the only variant `ex af,af'` (and a few others, but they are not shadow registers), and `exx` doesn't exchange `af`/`af'`, just the others. Good suggestion anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tip to start off: `jp` is generally a bad idea.

Unless your code is more than 128 bytes long (which it probably won't be), you can definitely save a byte with a `jr`. As a bonus, your code will be position-independent.

Just one quick warning: the offset of `jr` is from the start of the instruction on Z80 (so `18 00` is an infinite loop), but the end on SM83 (so `18 00` is a two-byte three-cycle no-op).

Therefore, `jr` on SM83 can offset the IP by any amount from -126 to 129, but on Z80 it's -128 to 127.

Answer (score 2):

### Use `ldir` and friends.

Instead of many successive loads, from the same location to a consecutive block of memory, you can use `ldir`:

```
    ld (mem),a
    ld (mem+1),a
    ld (mem+2),a
    ld (mem+3),a
    ld (mem+4),a
    ld (mem+5),a
```

... becomes:

```
    ld hl,mem
    ld de,mem+1
    ld (hl),a
    ld bc,5
    ldir
```

If you're familiar with x86 assembly, `ldir` is somewhat comparable to `rep movsb`. Of course, z80 has many more instructions like that: `cpir, inir, otir, lddr, cpdr, indr, otdr`

Answer (score 2):

### `cp` and `cpl`-related tricks

```
cp 0

cp 1
```

become respectively

```
or a

dec a
```

... saving a single byte. You can also use `cpl` instead of `xor $FF` to flip bits in a byte.

You can also use `cpl` for subtracting accumulator from some constant:

```
cpl
add a, X+1
```

... is one byte shorter than `neg` and `add a, X`

Answer (score 2):

### Messing with flags

You can do the following flag operations in a compact way:

- Carry flag: setting - `scf`, resetting - `or a`, alternatively `and a` (modifies sign and zero).
- Zero flag: setting - `cp a` (resets carry, modifies sign), resetting - `or 1` (resets carry, modifies `a` and sign).
- Sign flag: setting - `or $80` (reset zero and carry, modifies `a`), resetting - `xor a` (clear `a`, set zero, clear carry).
- Half carry: `and a` - set, `xor a` - reset.

Answer (score 1):

Another simple one:

**Use `xor a` or `sub a` instead of `ld a,0` to reset (load `0` to) the `a` register.**

Their use seems to be controversial in non-golfing situations (some sources use them, some advise against them), but I see no point in *not using* them:

- **They are 1 byte, while an immediate load is two bytes.**
- They are also faster (not generally a consideration for [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf)): they take 4 T-states, while an equivalent immediate load takes 7 T-states (8 on SM83).

They have a single side-effect: they modify the flags, while a load does not.
You can play around with this if you also want some flags to be set/reset.

On Z80, the flags are affected as follows:

| Flags: | `S` | `Z` | `H` | `P/V` | `N` | `C` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `xor a` | `0` | `1` | `0` | **`1`** | **`0`** | `0` |
| `sub a` | `0` | `1` | `0` | **`0`** | **`1`** | `0` |

Comment: (1 versus 2 CPU cycles, for the SM83.)

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn According to the table you've attached, it's 4 vs 8. The 1 vs 2 is the length in bytes...

Comment: That table lists cost in clock cycles, not CPU cycles, which each take four clock cycles (or eight on the CGB until you poke to a specific register).

Comment: @NoLongerBreathedIn Ok, I don't know the technical details of SM83, I know only Z80...

Comment: Surely `sub a` generates no half carry or overflow?

Comment: @Neil Yeah, that's right... Probably I wasn't paying enough attention when I was writing my post.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the most useful commands for golfing in Z80 assembly language are `sbc` and `adc`. They often allow you to interact with the flag C in ways that are absolutely amazing. Here are some cool examples:

1. **How to create a decreasing counter in A that stops at 0?** `or a : jr nz,$+3 : dec a` is ugly. `sub 1 : adc 0` is faster, runs in constant time and can often be size-optimized, if you have handy 0s or 1s in one of your other registers. Have to stop at a non-zero value N? No problem: `sub N : adc N-1`. This also works for incrementing counter that is clamped at 255: `add 1 : sbc 0`. This also works for a incrementing counter clamped at an arbitrary value N: `add 256-N : sbc 256-N-1`.
2. **How to load an arbitrary value N to A when flag C is up (or zero otherwise)?** `ld a,N : jr c,$+3 : xor a` is not the way. `sbc a : and N` usually is (it is faster and shorter by 2 bytes).
3. **How about loading into A value N if flag C is up or value M if flag C is down?** Don't mess with conditional jumps! Use `sbc a : and N-M : add M`. (This last trick I believe is invented by GriV).

Answer (score 0):

### Use `jp` instead of `call` and `ret`.

In some cases, `jp` is viable (contrary to the other answer). `call procedure / ret` can in some cases be replaced with `jp procedure`, saving one byte.

Comment: True, but what I meant was that one should use `jr` instead of `jp` whenever possible.